# Trying to start a server from the command line using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, server

I am a student, new to java networking, working on building a server to handle networked multiplayer for a Texas Holdem game implemented in javafx (this is our class final project), and I am trying to set it up in such a way that users can choose whether they want to host a new game, thus starting the server, or join someone else's server (on the same LAN). To this end, I have tried to start the server in a method executed when the user decides to host a game.

I have tried running the server using `ProcessBuilder` to run the java command on the compiled class file, but am not sure if it is successfully executing. I also wondered if I could avoid trying to get it to execute properly by making my server class a `Runnable` and reimplementing the "main" method as the "run" method.

Here is the code I used to run the server from the command line. The path to my server compiled class file is: `C:\Users\glacu\Desktop\SillySolitaire\build\classes\sillysolitaire`
I am running NetBeans 8.2 and the application runs from the `SillySolitaire` directory.

UPDATE: Changed the code to try and get the error stream and also print both lazily. I think this should work if the process is starting properly, but I am getting no output from either the error stream or the output stream.

```java
String javaExecutable = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";

        try{
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(javaExecutable, "-classpath", "build" + File.separator + "classes" + File.separator + "*", "sillysolitaire.GameServer").start();
            InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader isr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
            BufferedReader esr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            isr.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
            esr.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is the current server start code

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        targetPlayers = 2;
        gs = new GameState(targetPlayers);
        dealHands();
        System.out.println("Server is running...");
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(59001)) {
            while (playersInLobby < targetPlayers) {
                handler = new Handler(listener.accept());
                threadList.add(handler);
                pool.execute(handler);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The server starts just fine running the file directly but not when I try to run it using the ProcessBuilder.

UPDATE: This is I believe the exact command executed by the ProcessBuilder. 
`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java" -classpath C:\Users\glacu\Desktop\SillySolitaire\build\classes\* sillysolitaire.GameServer`

Executing it from my command line returns: Error: Could not find or load main class sillysolitaire.GameServer

I think something may be wrong with the -classpath option, and as such I have tried several different classpaths but all return the same error. Is there something else wrong with the command?

Comment: Output the full command line you are building before executing it. Keep in mind that `*` gets replaced by the terminal you are using, not by the "java" application (not sure if it is the case for windows). Also check the error stream from the process to see the errors you get from the application you start.

Comment: Not sure why spawning a new process is preferrable to running the server in a seperate thread... The problem seems completely unrelated to the JavaFX API though. Removed that tag...

Comment: Use a separate `Thread` to read the `Process` output and another separate `Thread` to read the `Process` error output and after starting both `Thread`s, call method `Process#waitFor()`. There are many examples available on the Web, like [Java ProcessBuilder examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-processbuilder-examples/)